# How to move canvas by element selection?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have my Canvas inside a scroolviewer with a large background image (width and height is double of my screen).
I put some shapes inside the canvas and I can select them from a listbox. When I select a shape from my listbox, the shape is highlighted.

The problem is that when I select a shape wich is out of the screen, I can't see where it is, so I want to move the canvas camera in order to see it. I can explain it better with an image:

[image]

Here if I select "shape 1" or "shape 2", I can see them highlighted 'cause them are into the screen, but if I select shape 3, it will be highlighted but I can't see where it is...I have to move my canvas in order to make shape 3 visible...

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can obtain a reference to Shape 3 you can use the `ScrollViewer`'s [BringIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.bringintoview(v=vs.110).aspx) method to scroll to the correct position:

```
UIElement shape3;

shape3.BringIntoView();
```

Comment: BringInfoView accepts only System.Windows.Rect.
I just used shape3.BringIntoView() and it's working. 
Thanks a lot!